# Arch Linux ARM on Raspberry pi from OSX

Tags: linux, macos, raspberry-pi, archlinux-arm

I'm trying to get Arch Linux ARM onto my RasPi 2 by doing the instructions [here under "Installation"](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2), but the commands are Linux commands, I am trying to format the SD with my Mac and so there are differences in the programs I'm trying to get around. For example `sudo fdisk /dev/sdX` on linux would result in an interactive prompt, on OSX it's different, instead I have to do fdisk -ie /dev/sdX to get an interactive prompt, and then the commands are different.

What I want to do on my mac is the same ad this process on linux:

> Start fdisk to partition the SD card: fdisk /dev/sdX At the fdisk
>   prompt, delete old partitions and create a new one:
>
> ```
> Type o. This will clear out any partitions on the drive.
> Type p to list partitions. There should be no partitions left.
> Type n, then p for primary, 1 for the first partition on the drive, press ENTER to accept the default first sector, then type +100M for the last sector.
> Type t, then c to set the first partition to type W95 FAT32 (LBA).
> Type n, then p for primary, 2 for the second partition on the drive, and then press ENTER twice to accept the default first and last sector.
> Write the partition table and exit by typing w.
> ```

But I'm not sure how to achive this with OSX's fdisk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible: you must use linux to install the tarball because you have to create an ext partition, which is not supported by OS X.

I had to reinstall Arch but I have just found out they don't distribute disk images anymore.
Some possible solutions are explained in this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/install-arch-linux-form-osx).

Comment: This answer is correct. I gave up on OSX and formatted the SD card on my PI instead. It was so much easier on rasbian.